# Firefox not displaying CSS updated via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, less

I'm implementing some sort of progress bar using HTML/CSS by using one div inside another:

```
<div class="composite-player-duration">
  <div class="composite-player-duration-amount"></div>
</div>
```

The inner `div` should grow inside the outer `div` horizontally. Here are the LESS style for the divs and the JavaScript function that implements the progress:

**style.less**

```css
.composite-player-duration {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.composite-player-duration-amount {
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  height: @height0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.1s;
  width: 0%;
}
```

**player.js**

```
function startCount() {
  playPauseButton.className = 'composite-playPause fa fa-pause';
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    played = video.currentTime;
    for (var i = currentSegment - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      played += segments[i].duration;
    };
    amount = (played/duration) * 100;
    $(durationAmount).css('width', amount + '%');
  }, 100)
}
```

In google chrome, everything works as expected. However, in Firefox, I can't see the bar grow. If I set `width` to another value other than `0%`  (let's say `50%`), I can see the bar stuck in this other value.

The weird thing is that if I log the `durationAmount` element, I can see the width value being updated:

```
<div class="composite-player-duration-amount" style="width: 4.17961%;">
```

Why is this `width` update not being displayed in the browser?

```js
var played = 0;
var duration = 300;
var durationAmount = document.getElementsByClassName('composite-player-duration-amount')[0];


setInterval(function() {
  var amount = (played/duration) * 100;
  $(durationAmount).css('width', amount + '%');
  played += 1;
}, 100)
```

```css
.composite-player-duration {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  height: 50px;
}

.composite-player-duration-amount {
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.1s;
  width: 0%;
}

**UPDATE:**
Snippet:
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="composite-player-duration">
      <div class="composite-player-duration-amount"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you check in IE,IE is best for JS related issue you can get it very easily

Comment: I assume you're setting durationAmount to a valid selector?

Comment: More useful to share the generated CSS than the .less file. Even better to do an [MCVE](/help/mcve) using Stack Snippets (the `<>` editor toolbar button) demonstrating the issue live.

Comment: $(".composite-player-duration-amount").css("width",(amount.toString()+%));

Comment: @Cruiser yes, I am. `<div class="composite-player-duration-amount" style="width: 4.17961%;">` is the output of `console.log(durationAmount)` And it works fine in chrome.

Comment: @VasimVanzara this wasn't helpful, unfortunately

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I'll update the question with a JSFiddle as soon as I can

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've edited the question to include the snippet. The weird thing is that it works on firefox as well...

Comment: The bar grows for me in Firefox using your snippet above. I'm using Firefox 44 on Linux.